# ngx-translate special chars issue

Tags: angular, ng2-translate, ngx-translate

In my angular 4 project I am using ngx-translate.
I have a problem with special chars like à, I see only a ?.
Do I need to use something particular to translate the special chars?
My project is in utf-8

[image]

Comment: The language file should be utf-8, its easy to fix you can open your language file in notepad and while doing save as select encoding as utf-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language file should have UTF-8 encoding, if you do that it should work fine.
There is an easy way to do that with notepad, you can do it any how you want.

```
1. Open the file in notepad
2. Click on save as 
3. Select encoding as UTF-8
```

[image]